# Move scrollbar of TableView to the left

Tags: java, javafx

I want to move the vertical scrollbar of a JavaFX TableView to the left (it is on the right by default). How can I achieve this? (I assume this will in a similar fashion for every JavaFX component that comes with a vertical scrollbar.)

Comment: not supported, you need a custom VirtualFlow (that's the part doing the layout) along with a custom TableViewSkin that allows to replace the original